# No signing certificate found iOS Dev & Re

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, provisioning-profile, apn

Unfortunately my MAC's original HDD was damaged so I had to replace it with a brand new SSD, after installing Xcode and tried to run the app I get the same error.
"No signing certificate "iOS Development" found"
"No signing certificate "iOS Distribution" found"

Revoking the certificate will risk stopping application to receive Push Notifications. Any possible solution other then revoking and losing Push Notification service?

Thank you!

Comment: If you didnt have a chance to export the dev profile, you may have to create new ones

Comment: I logged-in to my Apple's developer account and exported the provision profiles yet the issue presets. Showing "No signing certificate "iOS Distribution" found" evening when clicking manage certificates I see in status "missing private key"